# Access Token for Client Credentials Flow on Android

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, spotify

I'm working on an app where I am using the Spotify Web API to search for content. This is done from their search endpoint, which is documented [here](https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-search-item/?q=tania%20bowra&type=artist&market=&limit=&offset=). I am not trying to access any Spotify user-specific data. In fact, I don't want to require my users to have a Spotify account in order to use my app. All that I want to do is use the Spotify Web API to search for tracks, albums, and/or artists.

In order to do that, I need an access token to verify my application using a client secret and client ID, which I already have. I am trying to perform the Client Credentials Flow which is outlined [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow) in the Spotify documentation. However, I'm having some trouble doing that.

In my app, the activity which will make use of the Spotify Web API is not the launching activity. Therefore, the user can enter and exit this activity as often as they'd like. As of now, I'm getting the access token using Retrofit and following the guidelines of the Spotify docs. Here's what my code looks like:

```
private void retrieveAccessToken() {

    // First, we obtain an instance of SearchClient through our ClientGenerator class
    mClient = ClientGenerator.createClient(SearchClient.class);

    // We then obtain the client ID and client secret encoded in Base64.
    String encodedString = encodeClientIDAndSecret();

    // Finally, we initiate the HTTP request and hope to get the access token as a response
    Call<TokenResponse> tokenResponseCall = mClient.getAccessToken(encodedString, "client_credentials");
    tokenResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<TokenResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<TokenResponse> call, Response<TokenResponse> response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "on Response: response toString(): " + response.toString());
            TokenResponse tokenResponse = null;
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                tokenResponse = response.body();
                Log.d(TAG, "Access token value: " + tokenResponse.getAccessToken());
                mAccessToken = tokenResponse.getAccessToken();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<TokenResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: request toString():" + call.request().toString());
            mAccessToken = "";
        }
    });
}

private String encodeClientIDAndSecret(){
    String basic = "Basic ";
    String clientIDAndSecret = CLIENT_ID + ":" + CLIENT_SECRET;
    /*
    I use the NO_WRAP flag so that the encoded String is contained within a single line.
    Otherwise, there will be new line characters in the encoded String and we don't want to
    include those.
     */
    byte [] encodedValue = Base64.encode(clientIDAndSecret.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
    String encodedString = new String(encodedValue);

    // The final output needs to have both the encoded String as well as 'Basic ' prepended to it
    return basic + encodedString;
}
```

I call `retrieveAccessToken()` at the end of `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Initializing member variables and views within my activity
    retrieveAccessToken();
}
```

When the activity is launched for the first time, everything works as expected: I get my access token and can begin making search requests. However, if I press the back button and then re-enter the same activity, that's where things break. The next time `retrieveAccessToken()` is called, I get a response in my `Retrofit` callback, but the `TokenResponse` object has a 400 HTML error code, meaning to me that something has gone wrong. Here's what I have in Logcat when I print the `toString()` of the `Retrofit` `Response` object if I make subsequent calls to `retrieveAccessToken()`:

```
on Response: response toString(): Response{protocol=h2, code=400, message=, url=https://api.spotify.com/api/token}
```

Why is this happening? Yes, I realize that `retrieveAccessToken()` gets called each time that the activity is created, which is incredibly inefficient. However, I'm not sure how else I can make this request. One idea that I had was to somehow save the access token when the activity is no longer active, which I tried to do in `onSaveInstanceState()`. However, when the activity is relaunched, the `Bundle` in `onCreate()` is null....

I looked into using `AccountManager` as well, but I feel like going that route is overkill. I referred to this [developer doc](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate) as guidance. However, the main part that stumped me is where I would do the following:

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
Bundle options = new Bundle();

am.getAuthToken(
    myAccount_,                     // Account retrieved using getAccountsByType()
    "Manage your tasks",            // Auth scope
    options,                        // Authenticator-specific options
    this,                           // Your activity
    new OnTokenAcquired(),          // Callback called when a token is successfully acquired
    new Handler(new OnError()));    // Callback called if an error occurs
```

I don't want to have to call `getAccountsByType()` because again, I don't want to access the Spotify user's account data. I just want to be able to make search requests through the Spotify Web API.

I will admit that this is the first time where I'm dealing with OAuth 2.0. What is the best way to handle all of this? And the most secure for my situation?

Answer (score 0):

Try use charsets ISO_8859_1 because default UTF_8 lose some symbols when try to decode

```
String encodedString = new String(encodedValue, Charsets.ISO_8859_1);
```